# True or False: For some integers $p,q$ and $m$ if $p/q$ is in lowest terms, then $(p+m)/(q+m)$ is in lowest terms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The correct answer is supposedly true, but if $p = 5$, $q = 7$ and $m = 3$, then the statement is false since $(5 + 3)/(7 + 3) = \frac{8}{10}$, which is reducible to $\frac{4}{5}$. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: The statement is not saying that condition is true for all p,q,m. It's saying there *exist* p,q,m which make that condition true.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with $p=n$, $q=n+1$ and $m=1$?

Comment: I bet the statement is supposed to be, if $p/q$ is in lowest terms, then there is a positive $m$ such that $(p+m)/(q+m)$ is in lowest terms.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is that for *some* integers, the claim holds. In particular, take $p = 5, q = 7, m = 0$, and the result holds. You are correct that the statement does not hold for *all* integers.

Comment: Or take $p=q=m=2$, so that both fractions fail to be in lowest terms.  Making the conditional TRUE.